# What is the best way to make a Delphi Application completely full screen?

Tags: delphi, fullscreen, vcl, delphi-2007

What is the best way to make a Delphi application (Delphi 2007 for Win32) go completely full screen, removing the application border and covering the Windows Taskbar?

I am looking for something similar to what Internet Explorer (IE) does when you hit F11.

I wish this to be a run time option for the user not a design time decision by my good self.

As mentioned in the accepted answer

```
BorderStyle := bsNone;
```

was part of the way to do it.  Strangely I kept getting an `E2010 Incompatible types: 'TFormBorderStyle' and 'TBackGroundSymbol'` error when using that line (another type had `bsNone` defined).

To overcome this I had to use:

```
BorderStyle := Forms.bsNone;
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Well, this has always worked for me. Seems a bit simpler...

```
procedure TForm52.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  BorderStyle := bsNone;
  WindowState := wsMaximized;
end;
```

Comment: +1 Sometimes people try too hard: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/05/05/414910.aspx

Comment: Wow, i would not have believed it if i hadn't tested it myself. i *know* that setting `WindowsState := wsMaximized` will *not* cover the taskbar (it will be just a maximized window). So it was not unreasonable to assume that removing the border would lead to a maximized window with no border. But there's some undocumented trick somewhere (VCL or Windows) that removing the border of a maximized window will cause it to resize to fill the entire screen. (As opposed to Raymond's article where you explicitly size the form to the screen dimensions)

Comment: Windows 7 here (64bit) + Delphi XE 7: that *doesn't work*. The Windows taskbar still shows. Tested on Windows 8.1: same as W7 + the action bar that you can pull from the right is still available.

Comment: Edit: On Windows 7 **that works** (I forgot to remove the Align := alClient on the form). But on Windows 8.1 the action bar that you can pull from the right is still available. Any solution?

Answer (score 10):

A Google search turned up the following, additional methods:

(though I think I'd try Roddy's method first)

### [Manually fill the screen](http://delphi.about.com/cs/adptips2000/a/bltip0600_2.htm) (from: About Delphi)

```
procedure TSomeForm.FormShow(Sender: TObject) ;
var
   r : TRect;
begin
   Borderstyle := bsNone;
   SystemParametersInfo
      (SPI_GETWORKAREA, 0, @r,0) ;
   SetBounds
     (r.Left, r.Top, r.Right-r.Left, r.Bottom-r.Top) ;
end;
```

### Variation on a theme by Roddy

```
FormStyle := fsStayOnTop;
BorderStyle := bsNone;
Left := 0;
Top := 0;
Width := Screen.Width;
Height := Screen.Height;
```

### [The WinAPI way](http://groups.google.nl/group/borland.public.delphi.objectpascal/msg/1cc7e07b0e80150e?hl=en) (by Peter Below from TeamB)

```
private  // in form declaration
    Procedure WMGetMinMaxInfo(Var msg: TWMGetMinMaxInfo);
      message WM_GETMINMAXINFO;

Procedure TForm1.WMGetMinMaxInfo(Var msg: TWMGetMinMaxInfo);
  Begin
    inherited;
    With msg.MinMaxInfo^.ptMaxTrackSize Do Begin
      X := GetDeviceCaps( Canvas.handle, HORZRES ) + (Width - ClientWidth);
      Y := GetDeviceCaps( Canvas.handle, VERTRES ) + (Height - ClientHeight
);
    End;
  End;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
Const
  Rect: TRect = (Left:0; Top:0; Right:0; Bottom:0);
  FullScreen: Boolean = False;
begin
  FullScreen := not FullScreen;  
  If FullScreen Then Begin
    Rect := BoundsRect;
    SetBounds(
      Left - ClientOrigin.X,
      Top - ClientOrigin.Y,
      GetDeviceCaps( Canvas.handle, HORZRES ) + (Width - ClientWidth),
      GetDeviceCaps( Canvas.handle, VERTRES ) + (Height - ClientHeight ));
  //  Label2.caption := IntToStr(GetDeviceCaps( Canvas.handle, VERTRES ));
  End
  Else
    BoundsRect := Rect;
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

Maximize the form and [hide the title bar](http://delphi.about.com/cs/adptips2000/a/bltip0100_5.htm).  The maximize line is done from memory, but I'm pretty sure WindowState is the property you want.

There's also [this](http://www.delphicorner.f9.co.uk/articles/forms5.htm) article, but that seems too complicated to me.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject) ;
begin
   //maximize the window
   WindowState := wsMaximized;
   //hide the title bar
   SetWindowLong(Handle,GWL_STYLE,GetWindowLong(Handle,GWL_STYLE) and not WS_CAPTION);
   ClientHeight := Height;
end;
```

Edit:  Here's a complete example, with "full screen" and "restore" options.  I've broken out the different parts into little procedures for maximum clarity, so this could be greatly compressed into just a few lines.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    btnGoFullScreen: TButton;
    btnNotFullScreen: TButton;
    btnShowTitleBar: TButton;
    btnHideTitleBar: TButton;
    btnQuit: TButton;
    procedure btnGoFullScreenClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnShowTitleBarClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnHideTitleBarClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnNotFullScreenClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnQuitClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    SavedLeft : integer;
    SavedTop : integer;
    SavedWidth : integer;
    SavedHeight : integer;
    SavedWindowState : TWindowState;
    procedure FullScreen;
    procedure NotFullScreen;
    procedure SavePosition;
    procedure HideTitleBar;
    procedure ShowTitleBar;
    procedure RestorePosition;
    procedure MaximizeWindow;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.btnQuitClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Application.Terminate;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnGoFullScreenClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FullScreen;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnNotFullScreenClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  NotFullScreen;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnShowTitleBarClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowTitleBar;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnHideTitleBarClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  HideTitleBar;
end;

procedure TForm1.FullScreen;
begin
  SavePosition;
  HideTitleBar;
  MaximizeWindow;
end;

procedure TForm1.HideTitleBar;
begin
  SetWindowLong(Handle,GWL_STYLE,GetWindowLong(Handle,GWL_STYLE) and not WS_CAPTION);
  ClientHeight := Height;
end;

procedure TForm1.MaximizeWindow;
begin
  WindowState := wsMaximized;
end;

procedure TForm1.NotFullScreen;
begin
  RestorePosition;
  ShowTitleBar;
end;

procedure TForm1.RestorePosition;
begin
  //this proc uses what we saved in "SavePosition"
  WindowState := SavedWindowState;
  Top := SavedTop;
  Left := SavedLeft;
  Width := SavedWidth;
  Height := SavedHeight;
end;

procedure TForm1.SavePosition;
begin
  SavedLeft := Left;
  SavedHeight := Height;
  SavedTop := Top;
  SavedWidth := Width;
  SavedWindowState := WindowState;
end;

procedure TForm1.ShowTitleBar;
begin
  SetWindowLong(Handle,gwl_Style,GetWindowLong(Handle,gwl_Style) or ws_Caption or ws_border);
  Height := Height + GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYCAPTION);
  Refresh;
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 2):

Put to the form ***onShow*** event such code:

```
  WindowState:=wsMaximized;
```

And to the ***OnCanResize*** this:

```
  if (newwidth<width) and (newheight<height) then
    Resize:=false;
```

Answer (score 1):

How to constrain a sub-form within the Mainform like it was an MDI app., but without the headaches! (Note: The replies on this page helped me get this working, so that's why I posted my solution here)

```
private
{ Private declarations }
  StickyAt: Word;
  procedure WMWINDOWPOSCHANGING(Var Msg: TWMWINDOWPOSCHANGING); Message M_WINDOWPOSCHANGING;
  Procedure WMGetMinMaxInfo(Var msg: TWMGetMinMaxInfo); message WM_GETMINMAXINFO;
```

later...

```
    procedure TForm2.WMWINDOWPOSCHANGING(var Msg: TWMWINDOWPOSCHANGING);
    var
      A, B: Integer;
      iFrameSize: Integer;
      iCaptionHeight: Integer;
      iMenuHeight: Integer;
    begin

      iFrameSize := GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYFIXEDFRAME);
      iCaptionHeight := GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYCAPTION);
      iMenuHeight := GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYMENU);

      // inside the Mainform client area
      A := Application.MainForm.Left + iFrameSize;
      B := Application.MainForm.Top + iFrameSize + iCaptionHeight + iMenuHeight;

      with Msg.WindowPos^ do
      begin

        if x <= A + StickyAt then
          x := A;

        if x + cx >= A + Application.MainForm.ClientWidth - StickyAt then
          x := (A + Application.MainForm.ClientWidth) - cx + 1;

       if y <= B + StickyAt then
         y := B;

       if y + cy >= B + Application.MainForm.ClientHeight - StickyAt then
         y := (B + Application.MainForm.ClientHeight) - cy + 1;

      end;
end;
```

and yet more...

```
Procedure TForm2.WMGetMinMaxInfo(Var msg: TWMGetMinMaxInfo);
var
  iFrameSize: Integer;
  iCaptionHeight: Integer;
  iMenuHeight: Integer;
Begin
  inherited;
  iFrameSize := GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYFIXEDFRAME);
  iCaptionHeight := GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYCAPTION);
  iMenuHeight := GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYMENU);
  With msg.MinMaxInfo^.ptMaxPosition Do
  begin
    // position of top when maximised
    X := Application.MainForm.Left + iFrameSize + 1;
    Y := Application.MainForm.Top + iFrameSize + iCaptionHeight + iMenuHeight + 1;
  end;
  With msg.MinMaxInfo^.ptMaxSize Do
  Begin
     // width and height when maximized
     X := Application.MainForm.ClientWidth;
     Y := Application.MainForm.ClientHeight;
  End;
  With msg.MinMaxInfo^.ptMaxTrackSize Do
  Begin
     // maximum size when maximised
     X := Application.MainForm.ClientWidth;
     Y := Application.MainForm.ClientHeight;
  End;
  // to do: minimum size (maybe)
End;
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the only working solution is:

```
procedure TFormHelper.FullScreenMode;
begin
  BorderStyle := bsNone;
  ShowWindowAsync(Handle, SW_MAXIMIZE);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure Form position is poDefaultPosOnly.

```
Form1.Position := poDefaultPosOnly;
Form1.FormStyle := fsStayOnTop;
Form1.BorderStyle := bsNone;
Form1.Left := 0;
Form1.Top := 0;
Form1.Width := Screen.Width;
Form1.Height := Screen.Height;
```

Tested and works on Win7 x64.

Comment: What if you have dual monitor?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Align = alClient    
FormStyle = fsStayOnTop
```

This always align to the primary monitor;

Comment: What you wrote is not even close to code, missing double-dots, missing line separators, caused me a loss of 2 additional minutes when I needed a minute of acceleration. Please, either write complete useful code, or do not write at all. 
{code}
Align := alClient;
FormStyle := fsStayOnTop;
{code}

Answer (score 0):

Hm. Looking at the responses I seem to remember dealing with this about 8 years ago when I coded a game. To make debugging easier, I used the device-context of a normal, Delphi form as the source for a fullscreen display.

The point being, that DirectX is capable of running any device context fullscreen - including the one allocated by your form.

So to give an app "true" fullscreen capabilities, track down a DirectX library for Delphi and it will probably contain what you need out of the box.

Answer (score -1):

### VCL

Here are two button click events to go into FullScreen and to exit FullScreen:

```
procedure TForm1.GoFullScreen(Sender: TObject);
begin
  BorderStyle := bsNone;
  WindowState := wsMaximized;
end;

procedure TForm1.ExitFullScreen(Sender: TObject);
begin
  BorderStyle := bsSizable;
  WindowState := wsNormal;
end;
```

### FMX

And for those finding themselves here looking to do the same in FireMonkey (FMX). The VCL method of changing `BorderStyle` and `WindowState` will kind of work in FMX, but the correct way is to use the `FullScreen` property on the form in FMX:

```
procedure TForm1.GoFullScreen(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FullScreen := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.ExitFullScreen(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FullScreen := False;
end;
```