# Prevent Any Application from Minimizing Mine

Tags: forms, delphi, vcl, minimize

I'm wondering if there's a good way to prevent any application from Minimizing my Delphi form? I currently have a borderless VCL form and the WindowState is set to wsMaximized. I'd like to keep it in the maximized state permanently. Any advice on how to do this would be most wonderful. Thank you

Comment: Sensing an XY question, do consider perhaps an [embedded](https://download.microsoft.com/download/C/E/5/CE5DAF5E-86E1-4AEE-AFF0-1E0975ABB1DE/Windows%20Embedded%20Version%20Overview.pdf) or [kiosk mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-single-app) deployment for this application.  It sounds like that's what you want.

Comment: As per  possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943551/dont-want-form-to-minimize , you can remove the biMinimize BorderIcon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Override your Form's virtual `WndProc()` method and have it discard any [`WM_SYSCOMMAND`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-syscommand) messages whose `wParam` contains `SC_MINIMIZE` or `SC_RESTORE`.

Comment: This works fine from within my own window but other programs are still able to minimize my window. I've just tested with Process Explorer by selecting my process, right-clicking and using the built-in Window menu to Minimize.

Comment: var
     lpOldWndProc: PVOID = nil;


function NewWndProc(Window: HWND; Msg, WP: Integer; LP: Integer): Integer; stdcall;
begin
     if (wP = SC_MINIMIZE) or (wP = SC_RESTORE) then
     result := 0
  else
     result := CallWindowProc(PVOID(lpOldWndProc), Window, Msg, WP, LP)
end;


procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
     lpOldWndProc := PVOID(SetWindowLongPtr(Form1.Handle, GWL_WNDPROC, NativeInt(@NewWndProc)));
end;

Comment: Ugh, that's nasty. Do it the way Remy said.

Comment: Wouldn't the effect be the same though?

Comment: @WayOfTheWright you need to check `Msg = WM_SYSCOMMAND` before looking at `WP`. But even if you don't `override` the `WndProc()` method like I suggested, you can use the `WindowProc` property instead of using `SetWindowLongPtr()` manually (and even then, `SetWindowSubclass()` would have been more preferred).  But yes, the end effect would be the same no matter how you subclass the window procedure.  Try intercepting the [`WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-windowposchanging) message instead and see what happens

Comment: Yes, the effect would be the same. So use the clean method and not the hack that breaks in the face of window recreation.

Comment: That would be true only if I were dynamically creating forms, but I'm not in this case. Form1 remains statically created so it's never recreated. I will keep this in mind though for future reference.

Comment: I said window recreation and not form recreation. The window can be recreated in certain circumstances and your code will break. Don't use your hack. Do it either of the ways Remy said.

Comment: Understood. I've since used the virtual WndProc as per his suggestion. "The window can be recreated in certain circumstances" I've literally never observed this happening. This window you refer to would be accessed from Form1.Handle in my case and that handle remains the same throughout the lifetime of my "Form" so I have no idea what you're referring to. Also, if a window was recreated wouldn't that trigger the VCL to again call event handlers such as FormCreate() again? That would be dangerous

Comment: @WayOfTheWright "*This window you refer to would be accessed from Form1.Handle*" - yes.  The HWND assigned to the `Handle` can be recreated by the VCL dynamically, creating a new HWND. It is less likely for a Form, more likely for child controls, but it *can* happen for a Form, too. "*if a window was recreated wouldn't that trigger the VCL to again call event handlers such as FormCreate() again?*" - no, because such events are Form events not window events. The Form is not being recreated, just its HWND.

Comment: You might never have observed window recreation for your forms, but it can and does happen. So if you must apply customisations to your window then use `CreateParams` or `CreateWnd/DestroyWindowHandle`.

Comment: Note that `SetWindowPlacement`, `ShowWindow` etc.. do not generate system commands but they can minimize a window.

Comment: Ok, thanks to all 3 of you (David, Remy and Sertac) for the great information