# Delphi 10.4 fullscreen Iframe video in TAdvWebBrowser

Tags: delphi, iframe, fullscreen, vcl, delphi-10.4-sydney

I have a video in Iframe format in the TAdvWebBrowser. When I click on a fullscreen button nothing happens.

```
var HTML:='<iframe src="'+URL+'"frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;"</iframe>';

WebBrowser.LoadHTML(HTML);
```

I need the video show fullscreen.
Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In order to show video in FullScreen you need to do the following

1. Switch your application into a full screen window. [What is the best way to make a Delphi Application completely full screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14472/3636228)
2. Resize your browser component so that it fills the entire window.

EDIT: Looking at [TAdvWebBrowser developer guide](http://www.tmssoftware.biz/Download/Manuals/TMS%20TAdvWebBrowser%20Developers%20Guide.pdf) it doesn't sem that `TAdvWebBrowser` supports detecting when a HTML element of a web page is entering or leaving FullScreen mode.